# Codeigniter Model Function and query Not working

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

Iam try to run a query in codeigniter model.Its working but when I echo model function query is like below.

```html
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '17'
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '20'
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '21'
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '22'
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '23'
```

My model function is given below

```html
function get_quick_navi_menu($q_code)
{
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->where('q_id',$q_code);
$this->db->from("table0");
$q = $this->db->get();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
$final = array();
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) 
{
foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table1");
$this->db->where("id",$row->id);
$q = $this->db->get();
echo $this->db->last_query();
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
$row->children = $q->result();
}
array_push($final, $row);
}
}
```

I want to run query like below

```html
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '17,18,19..'
```

Table Structure

```html
Table0

id   q_id  value1

1      2       4

2      2       5

3      2       6

Table1

t1_id   id  value1   value2

 1      1      2         2
 
 2      2      5         6
 
 3      3      8         12
```

View

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="margin-left: 1px; opacity: .9;">
      
      <?php foreach ($menus as $menu) { ?> 
                         <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="pan-btn" data-look="<?php echo $menu->sceneid;?>"><?php echo $menu->title;?></a>  
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">        <?php
            if (isset($menu->children)) {
                foreach ($menu->children as $child) {?>
                
                <li><a href="#" class="pan-btn" data-look="<?php echo $child->menu_scene;?>"><?php echo $child->menu_item;?></a></li> <?php
                }
            }
            ?></ul></li><?php } ?>
       </ul>
```

Controller

```html
$menus = $this->Home_model->get_quick_navi_menu($q_code);
$data = array('menus' => $menus);
```

Required Output

Selecting value1 and value2 from table1 according to id from table0.
How to solve this please help.

Comment: i think you need where in.

Comment: tried where_in but not worked @Devsi Odedra

Comment: post your table structure and required output here.

Comment: table structure updated@Devsi Odedra

Comment: required output?

Comment: what is required is updated@Devsi Odedra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you;**

Get all `ids` in an array name here ids and use `where_in` outside the loop

```
public function get_quick_navi_menu($q_code)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where('q_id',$q_code);
    $this->db->from("table0");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $final = array();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($q->result() as $key => $row) 
        {
            $ids[$key] = $row->id;
            $data[$key] = $row;
        }

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("table1");
        $this->db->where_in("id",$ids);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            if ( ! empty($data))
            {
                foreach ($data as $key => $item) 
                {
                    $item->children = $q->result();
                    $final[] = $item;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return $final;
    /*print_r($final);*/
}
```

In your controller class:

*make sure you have loaded your model and database in controller or in autoload.php*

```
 $q_code = 'q_code_value';
 $data['menus'] =$this->Home_model->get_quick_navi_menu($q_code);
 /* pass the $data in the view like this*/
 $this->load->view('your_view_file_path',$data);
```

In your view :

```
<div><?php print_r($records);?></div>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: query is working.How to get these values in controller and view@pradeep

Comment: just call the model  in your controller and pass the data in the veiw

Comment: see my updated answer, how to pass the data to the view

Comment: if my answer helps you , pls don't hesitate to check it as green

Comment: Updated wit my view and controller pls have a look@pradeep

Comment: see my updated answer, changes only in the $data variable in controller's method, keep view part  the same

Comment: controller method:$data["menus"] = $this->Home_model->get_quick_navi_menu($q_code);@pradeep

Comment: it should be like as in my answer where model and view are called at the same place, what u showing me is just a model called

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Problem was model function was not returning anything.added return $final; in model and worked.@pradeep

Comment: is there something wrong with my answer, you uncheck it from green may i know the reason

Comment: so now downvote . is it very tough for you to judge whether it is helpful or not , are you confused enough. should i remove my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in controller

```
public function getTableData()
    {
        $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(id) as id');
        $tbl0 = $this->db->get('table0')->row_array();
        if($tbl0) {
                $ids = explode(',', $tbl0['id']);
                $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
                $tbl1 = $this->db->get('table1')->result_array();
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($tbl1);

        }
    }
```